# Accidentally uninstalled Ubuntu 14.04 system settings. How to get them back?

Tags: 14.04, system-settings

Somehow, cleaning  up useless software (using software center),  I uninstalled Ubuntu "system settings". I did this by mistake. Now I fail to find system settings application using software center (and there are so many items in history...).

It seems strange to me because usually when I try to uninstall something critical (system testing for example), the dependencies manager tells me It will uninstall the whole desktop system then. I am sure I did not have that warning.

So I need the name of the software to install or a command line command rather than a system restore to get it back.

Very interesting thing. If you ever want to play with this and reproduce it, you will be confused to see **Ubuntu Mobile** system settings instead! Yes, mobile network and touchscreen settings! Happy pre-release viewing!

Comment: You should post the output of `sudo apt-get -s install ubuntu-desktop` to http://pastebin.com. Someone might know what to install back. The `-s` part will make sure nothing is actually installed.

Comment: @mikewhatever actually, I've solved it thanks to your idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found this was `unity-control-center`. I expected it to have keywords "settings" or "system" or "configuration", but I did not use the full power of my imagination :)

```
 sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

gets everything back.

Important note. Never try to uninstall things that seem system-dependent using `apt-get purge`. In my case I wanted to get rid of `ibus` because I never need it. But it uninstalled unity-control-center as a dependency. Others might be frustrated with bluetooth or printer or whatever services running on their machine, which they consider unneeded. Do not try to just purge those things, there should be another way.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing (or reinstalling) the package `ubuntu-desktop` by:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```